# How to initialize Facebook Javascript SDK with a token without using Login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I have a long-living Facebook token and would like to use it in the Facebook Javascript SDK, but I can't find a way to do it!

I don't want to use their Facebook Login procedure, cause I already have the token. I'd like to be able to use the ui() function to add new payment methods to my ad account.
Does someone know any ways to do it? Thanks in advance.

P.S. Or maybe you know any other ways to add payment methods programmaticaly? That would be superb!

Comment: hardcoded tokens should not be used in client code. tokens are meant to be kept secret. use it server side instead.

Comment: Calling that dialog itself does not involve any access token in the first place. (If you need to perform a check what payment methods were added after, you’d need an access token, yes. You could do that on the server side however.)

Comment: @luschn I can't use token on the server side, cause on the server side there are no API methods to add credit cards!

Comment: @04FS yep, you can call that method without any tokens, and it will check, if the user is logged in (some of the inner sdk variables are initialized) and if not - it will redirect to the Login procedure. But I don't need to be redirected! I already have the token.